# SQL Vertical grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have the following RDB Table:

```
ID  Feature
1   1
1   2
2   1
3   1
3   2
3   3
```

What I want is the following output:

```
ID  Feature1    Feature2    Feature3
1   true        true        false
2   true        false       false
3   true        true        true
```

What's the simplest SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: are there only 3 features or can you have many more?

Comment: The more generalized the better but for now, we can safely assume that there are just 3 features

Comment: This is mysql, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the id's with all feature combinations using a `cross join` and `left join` the original table on to this to get the required result.

```
select i.id,
max(case when f.feature=1 and t.feature is not null then 'true' else 'false' end) as feature1,
max(case when f.feature=2 and t.feature is not null then 'true' else 'false' end) as feature2,
max(case when f.feature=3 and t.feature is not null then 'true' else 'false' end) as feature3
from (select distinct feature from t) f --replace this with the feature table if you have one
cross join (select distinct id from t) i
left join t on t.id=i.id and t.feature=f.feature
group by i.id
```

If you just need boolean values 1,0 for True,False the query can be simplified to

```
select i.id,
max(f.feature=1 and t.feature is not null) as feature1,
max(f.feature=2 and t.feature is not null) as feature2,
max(f.feature=3 and t.feature is not null) as feature3
from (select distinct feature from t) f --replace this with the feature table if you have one
cross join (select distinct id from t) i
left join t on t.id=i.id and t.feature=f.feature
group by i.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you would need is a simple pivot query. Here, I used boolean values to flag whether or not a feature exists (1 for true, 0 for false).

```
SELECT  f.ID 
      , Feature1    =   SUM(CASE WHEN f.Feature = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      , Feature2    =   SUM(CASE WHEN f.Feature = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      , Feature2    =   SUM(CASE WHEN f.Feature = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

FROM    dbo.Features        (NOLOCK)     f

GROUP BY f.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need conditional aggregation:

```
select id, max(feature = 1) as feature1, max(feature = 2) as feature2,
       max(feature = 3) as feature3
from t
group by id;
```

The above returns 0 and 1.  If you actually want the strings `true` and `false`, you can do:

```
select id,
       (case when max(feature = 1) then 'true' else 'false' end) as feature1,
       (case when max(feature = 2) then 'true' else 'false' end) as feature2,
       (case when max(feature = 3) then 'true' else 'false' end) as feature3
from t
group by id;
```